# POST Request Json file passing String and wait for the response Volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I am new to Android and Volley, and I need your help.
I need to post a String, have a json to response to it and, if it doesn't raise a bad request, start a new intent with some values coming from my request.

This is a simple schema of what I want to do:
Press Login button -> star request -> check if it is ok -> start a new intent with response values.

I have seen that Volley uses asynchronous method to query.
Here's my code:

```
boolean temp=false;
     login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean temp=false;
                     if (!id.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !pw.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        temp = verifyCredentials(v.getContext()); //Doesn't work because Volley is asynchronous.

                     if(temp==true)
                     {
                         Intent intentMain = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);//MainActivity.class);
                         intentMain.putExtra("username", id.getText().toString());
                         startActivityForResult(intentMain, 0);
                     }
                } else {//strighe vuote
                    //toast
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Compila i campi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });

public boolean verifyCredentials(Context context) {
        final boolean[] tempToReturn = {false};
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                mTextView.setText("Response is:" + response.substring(500));
                tempToReturn[0] =true;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String json = null;
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if(response != null && response.data != null){
                    switch(response.statusCode){
                        case 400:
                            json = new String(response.data);
                            json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                            if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                            break;
                    }
                    //Additional cases
                }
                mTextView.setText("Error bad request");
            }
            public String trimMessage(String json, String key){
                String trimmedString = null;

                try{
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                    trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
                } catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

                return trimmedString;
            }

            //Somewhere that has access to a context
            public void displayMessage(String toastString){
                mTextView.setText("Response is:" +toastString);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                AuthenticationUserName = id.getText().toString();
                AuthenticationPassword = pw.getText().toString();
                params.put("grant_type", Authenticationgrant_type);
                params.put("username", AuthenticationUserName);
                params.put("password", AuthenticationPassword);
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return  tempToReturn[0];
    }
```

I am using Volley because my gradle's is the 23 and my APi level too so I can't use the apache package.

EDIT: NEW CODE:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean temp = true;
                if (!id.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !pw.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    myContext = v.getContext();
                    VolleyResponseListener listener = new VolleyResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                            String json = null;
                            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                            if(response != null && response.data != null){
                                switch(response.statusCode){
                                    case 400:
                                        json = new String(response.data);
                                        json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                                        if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                                        break;
                                }
                                //Additional cases
                            }
                            mTextView.setText("Error bad request");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                            try {
                                fullName = response.getString("fullName");
                                token= response.getString("access_token");
                                expirationDate=response.getString(".expires");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mTextView.setText("Response is:" + fullName+token+expirationDate);
                            Intent intentMain = new Intent(myContext, MainActivity.class);//MainActivity.class);
                            intentMain.putExtra("username", id.getText().toString());
                            startActivityForResult(intentMain, 0);
                        }

                        public String trimMessage(String json, String key){
                            String trimmedString = null;
                            try{
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                                trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
                            } catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }

                            return trimmedString;
                        }

                        //Somewhere that has access to a context
                        public void displayMessage(String toastString){
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mTextView.setText("Response is:" +toastString);
                        }
                    };

                    verifyCredentials(myContext,listener);
```

and I have create this interface:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(VolleyError error);
    void onResponse(JSONObject  response);
}
```

And here is the new code of my verifycredential:

```
   public boolean verifyCredentials(Context context,final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        final boolean[] tempToReturn = {false};
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        AuthenticationUserName = id.getText().toString();
        AuthenticationPassword = pw.getText().toString();
                    //key value
        params.put("grant_type", Authenticationgrant_type);
        params.put("username",  AuthenticationUserName);
    params.put("password", AuthenticationPassword);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    SimpleRequest jsObjRequest  = new SimpleRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiURL,
            params,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                    listener.onResponse(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            listener.onError(error);
        }
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    return  tempToReturn[0];
}
```

Comment: just show a progress dialog before, and when request finish volley will auto call callback response or error

Comment: @MamataGelanee the url is my personalApi, I don't wont to share it.... sorry

Comment: @SacreDeveloper can you post me some example code?thank you

Comment: look on @BNK answer below, it should help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered some questions that look like your issue, such as:

[Android: How to return async JSONObject from method using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375295/android-how-to-return-async-jsonobject-from-method-using-volley)

You should not wait for that boolean return value. Instead, you can try the following way (of course, you can replace `JSONArray` request by `JSONObject` or `String` request):

```
VolleyResponseListener listener = new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                // do something...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                // do something...
            }
        };

makeJsonArrayRequest(context, Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, listener);
```

Body of `makeJsonArrayRequest` can be as the following:

```
    public void makeJsonArrayRequest(Context context, int method, String url, String requestBody, final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        JSONObject jsonRequest = null;        
        try {
            ...
            if (requestBody != null) {
                jsonRequest = new JSONObject(requestBody);
            }
            ...
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                listener.onResponse(jsonArray);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.onError(error.toString());
            }
        });

        // Access the RequestQueue through singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

`VolleyResponseListener` interface as the following:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(String message);

    void onResponse(Object response);
}
```

**For your comments below:**

> *first of all is: the "order" of the method, for example in my case,
>   After pressing button, which method I have to call?*

Let's assume we are inside `onCreate`:
You can create `VolleyResponseListener listener` first, then call `verifyCredentials(..., listener);` when pressing the button.

> *And where I can call the intent?*

This will be called inside `onResponse` of the above `VolleyResponseListener  listener` (of course, inside that you can check more conditions depend on your requirements)

> *Second: I have to send a String but I want a jsonArrayRespond, there
>   is a method to do this? Or it work only with 2 kind of parameter such
>   string request/string sent and json request/json sent?*

According to [Google's training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html):

- StringRequest: Specify a URL and receive **a raw string in response**.
- ImageRequest: Specify a URL and receive **an image in response**.
- JsonObjectRequest and JsonArrayRequest (both subclasses of
  JsonRequest): Specify a URL and get a **JSON object** or **array**
  (respectively) **in response**.

And of course you can implement your own custom request types, for types that don't have out-of-the-box Volley support. Take a look at [Implementing a Custom Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand many "stupid" things, first of all is: the "order" of the method, for example in my case, After pressing button, which method I have to call?And where I can call the intent?
Second: I have to send a String but I want a jsonArrayRespond, there is a method to do this? Or it work only with 2 kind of parameter such string request/string sent and json request/json sent? Thank you

Comment: thank you for the reply;I tried to do what you have wrote but It doesn't work....... The application crash after I pressed the button, with debugging's mode I have saw that the problem is after It executes the function verycredential, because It does nothing else. I have modified the code. What I have to change/do now? thank you

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException:
at myproject.LoginActivity$1$1.onError(LoginActivity.java:112)->mTextView.setText("Error bad request");
at myproject.LoginActivity$3.onErrorResponse(LoginActivity.java:220)->   listener.onError(error);
at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:563)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
....

Comment: Check if your `mTextView` is null or not

Comment: Normally, `mTextView` inititialization at the beginning of `onCreate`, like this `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Comment: It is inizialied.... =( but one time the error is on the mTextView.setText("‌​Error bad request"); and other time it is on the    mTextView.setText("Response is:" + fullName+token+expirationDate);

Comment: NullPointerException perhaps something null, I think you should check more when debug. Moreover, you should post the screenshot having mTextView value when debugging so that I can check more

Comment: I have saw on my degub that mtextView is null.. but I really don't understand, because I have set them on oncreate and onstart too. Now I try to remove them and look if it works

Comment: Have you declared textView2 in the layout XML file?

Comment: Yes... It is declared in my layout_login and It exist.. I really don't understand

Comment: Post your layout file content and onCreate's content pls. If textView init already inside onCreate, no need onStart. Another way, put the pointer at `R.id.textView2` inside `verifyCredentials`, then press Ctrl-B to check if it jumps to the correct layout file or not

Comment: I have put mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
before mTextView.setText and now it works. Very thank you for your help! =)

Comment: Glad my answer could help!

Comment: You can read [my new answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551668/android-volley-static-vs-object/32642986?noredirect=1#comment53137764_32642986) to see another way (order) of using listener interface.