# Volley Request Callback passing the wrong callback response

Tags: android, json, callback, request, android-volley

I've added a callback on the volley request and, I have two request started from 2 different activity. When I perform the first request, then the second return the response of the first..

This is my request and callback:

```
public static void RequestJsonToServer(Context ctx, final JSONObject params, final VolleyCallback callback){

    MySingleVolley.getInstance(ctx).
            getRequestQueue();

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,ctx.getString(R.string.defaultServerRequestUrl),params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response);
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("REQUEST_JSON_TO_SERVER", "Error: " + error);
                }
            }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }
            };

    MySingleVolley.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}

public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(JSONObject string);
}
```

And this is one of the two starting request:

```
Global.RequestJsonToServer(getActivity(), jsonObject, new Global.VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I hope someone can help me

Thanks

**Edit:**
I change it like this

```
Global.RequestJsonToServer(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject, new Global.VolleyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccessCustom(JSONObject string) {

        }
    }, true);
```

And the other one with false.. But maybe is the wrong way to use it..I would like to have one single callback and reuse it, not switch between two callbacks

**MY SOLUTION**

I've found my own solution, the problem wasn't in the callback but was in the volley request. The response of each request was cached and i don't know why, it will be return the wrong always the wrong response.

I've just added this before adding request to queue:

```
jsObjRequest.setShouldCache(false);
```

Comment: Please take a look at my 2 answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375295/android-how-to-return-async-jsonobject-from-method-using-volley/32379539#32379539) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627089/post-request-json-file-passing-string-and-wait-for-the-response-volley/32627293#32627293)

Comment: Ok I see it, but is the same that I have before posting the answere here, i have always the respinse of the later REQUEST!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your callback method is common[onSuccess(...)]why don't you write 2 call backs and based on the condition use the required callback.
To implement it write 2 methods in your interface and pass some sort of flag to choose callback.
Change your interface to this.

```
public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(JSONObject string);
    void customOnSuccess(JSONObject string);
}
```

And your method to this

```
public static void RequestJsonToServer(boolean flag,Context ctx, final JSONObject params, final VolleyCallback callback){

    MySingleVolley.getInstance(ctx).
            getRequestQueue();

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,ctx.getString(R.string.defaultServerRequestUrl),params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(flag){
                    callback.onSuccess(response);
                    }else{
                    callback.CustomOnSuccess(response);
                   }
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("REQUEST_JSON_TO_SERVER", "Error: " + error);
                }
            }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }
            };

    MySingleVolley.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}
```

Yes its reusable use onSucces where ever you have only one callback use both when you have more than one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm looking right for that.. Can you please make me an example of that??? Thanks

Comment: But I've to do a lot of request and i would like to make a reusable callback, not one for each request..

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: And the usage is when I've to use one callback I'll pass true, instead for the other callback I'll pass false?

Comment: the code is proper it's not working because you are creating a new instance of request object. There should be only one request object per app. please modify your code accordingly[implement singelton pattern] then it will start working i posted the code after testing it

Comment: could you try after making these changes also refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo and this https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Comment: Okay, can you post some more code about the implementation of singleton pattern? thanks

Comment: I can't resolve this problem.. Please can you show me how to create a singleton pattern and on to use it when i make the request? please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91388/discussion-between-dvdciri-and-war-hero).