# Method returned a value but the value not passed correctly

Tags: java, android, parameters, try-catch, android-volley

I need to return some data from a remote server to my app using Volley request, but after some time testing it I'm unable to get it working.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
String recipientUsername = foo;
picture = retrievedPicture(recipientUsername);
Log.i(TAG, "String picture: " + picture);
recipientPicture = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.chat_image_circle_pic);
recipientPicture.setImageUrl(picture, imageLoader);
```

So `picture` is declared globally to retrieve a value from a method with Volley inside. In my log when the above lines are read look like this:

```
I/ChatActivity: String picture: null
```

Which gets more confusing when the method itself is actually returning something. The method looks like this:

```
public String retrievedPicture(final String username) {
    // Tag used to cancel request
    String tag_string_req = "req_update_user";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_RETRIEVE, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User is retrieving on MySQL: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // Do no changes on SQLite at the moment
                    JSONObject userObj = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    picture = userObj.getString("picture");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Picture retrieved from MySQL: " + picture);
                } else {
                    // Error occurred in updating user's data. Get the error message from php node:
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Log.e(TAG, errorMsg);
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in retrieving user's data: " + error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting the params to php (nodes, data to be changed)
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("tag", "retrievepic");
            params.put("username", username);
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to the request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);

    return picture;
}
```

And the log shows the method does work:

```
D/ChatActivity: User is retrieving on MySQL: {"tag":"retrievepic","error":false,"uid":19,"user":{"username":"test07","picture":"http:\/\/192.168.0.3\/worka\/uploads\/test07_05112015_155304.jpg"}}
D/ChatActivity: Picture retrieved from MySQL: http://192.168.0.3/worka/uploads/test07_05112015_155304.jpg
```

So what I could guess is that I'm not passing anything from the try catch block of the method. If so, what can I do to get the value passed correctly? The try catch block is already nested inside a void method that seems fixed. I'm really hoping there's a solution to this so I can make the method into a utility class too. Thanks for reading guys!

Comment: Please read my answer at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535435/how-to-create-a-proper-volley-listener-for-cross-class-volley-method-calling/33535554#33535554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `picture` is always null when you return it as a result from your method.

Volley request are asynchronous - they are executed on a worker thread and return a result sometime in the future. You are notified that the result is there in `onResponse()`. This is why you see the correct thing in your logcat.

At the time you return `picture` as a result from the method, the request has not been executed yet and the value of `picture` is `null`.

As a solution, you should change the return type of the method, executing the request to `void` and move the image loading logic to `onResponse()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as that cleared out a lot especially the asynchronous task. I did put it in the `onReponse()` initially, but I thought about turning it into a utility class where I could keep on using the code effortlessly. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. I would recommend you separate the actual code for making the request and parsing the response. It may serve you as a kind of controller or an API client. You can expose a method looking like this  `retrieveImage(Listener listener)`, where `Listener` is a callback interface with two methods - `onImageLoaded(String imagePath)` and `onError()`. Inside your fragment/activity you call the `retrieveImage(Listener)` method and provide a callback implementation, where you set the image URL on your `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks @danail-alexiev, that was helpful! Using `Listener` for this feat is relatively new for me, but I'm slowly getting the picture. Is there a link or some keywords I could find to give myself more pointers implementing this?

Comment: You can start with this: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

> So what I could guess is that I'm not passing anything from the try
>   catch block of the method.

You are returning the current value of `picture`. You are doing the wrong assumption that the UI Thread is waiting for

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue
```

to finish. And that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

`retrievedPicture()` method will return default value of picture is obvious, Because `volley will execute request asynchronously`.

In line `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);`. You are `executing volley request` which is `asynchronous`, So i`n very next line you are returning picture, yet volley response is not received`. that's why your method is returning `default value`.

You should execute `recipientPicture.setImageUrl(picture, imageLoader);` inside `onResponse()` method, where volley Response received.

Answer (score 1):

The `picture` return before `onResponse`.

Try to use `EventBus`.

Use `EventBus` post a `Event`.

Than  you can get the event and go on.