# How to access Android module application context

Tags: android, android-volley, android-module

I have created an android module(module project) that helps to access HTTP calls (Http Module wrap volley). I want to make  Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext); into a place that initialize once rather than creating every time (To avoid memory overflows). A better place would be the Application class but from the module, I do not want to access the application. Is there any place I can initialize volley requestQue once and then use it. Was there a component like application in the module?

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535435/how-to-create-a-proper-volley-listener-for-cross-class-volley-method-calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did create a singleton class in my module  to get the request

```
public class RequestQueSingleton {
    private static RequestQueSingleton sSoleInstance;
    private static RequestQueue reQuestQue;

    private RequestQueSingleton(){}  //private constructor.

    public static RequestQueSingleton getInstance(Context context){
        if (sSoleInstance == null){ //if there is no instance available... create new one
            sSoleInstance = new RequestQueSingleton();
            reQuestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }

        return sSoleInstance;
    }


    public  synchronized RequestQueue getInstance() {
        Log.d("Request Que Obj",reQuestQue.hashCode()+"");
        return reQuestQue;
    }
}
```