# Callback in android(Network call in separate class)

Tags: java, android, xml, callback, android-volley

I have layout xml name main.xml and i have main.java class in that class now i send network call and get data from rest service.But now i want to separate network call in anohther class.How can i do that.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callsubclass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call sub-class" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonCallSubClass = (Button)findViewById(R.id.callsubclass);
        textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

       // i can set network call here and update TExtview

       textResult .setText(result);
    }
```

rest service response =`{"id":1958,"content":"Hello, World!"}`

my separate nework.java class

```
String url1 = String.format("http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url1, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("Test", response.toString());
                        String token="a";
                        String id="";
                        String result="";
                        try {
                            id= response.get("id").toString();
                            result= response.get("content").toString();
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }
```

now i want to do network call in separate class give a solution.

Comment: where is the problem in this?

Comment: But now i want to separate network call in anothher class. => Dude as you mentioned above,you already have a separate network class!

Comment: But i cant update my UI(xml) in separated class from the result of rest service

Comment: Read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627089/post-request-json-file-passing-string-and-wait-for-the-response-volley/32627293#32627293). Hope this helps!

Comment: And [one more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551668/android-volley-static-vs-object/32642986?noredirect=1#comment53137764_32642986)

Comment: @BNK i read your post but i cant understand how can i apply it to my project.can you explain me how  it apply for my project.

Comment: Ok. Use and interface or callbacks, Override in your main activity your custom método/ metods, pass your callback to your rest callback and ok success Override your custom method of callback, so in your activity Override you can update te ui. Is the best way

Comment: @MaxPinto can you give me a example with my above codes.

Comment: Read my sample code in the two links I sent above. It's easy to understand if you already used Volley.

Comment: Done it.Thanks BNK,Max Pinto and others

Comment: Glad it could help, you should post your solution as an answer to this question for other men's reference