# AsyncTask is still blocking UI(UI not responding)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I have a news app where I fetch a couple of XMLs and APIs and insert into database at once. I'm using AsyncTask during the fetching/inserting into Database process. However I still get a block(UI Doesn't not respond)

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
    MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask =  new MyAsyncTask(urls.get(i));
    myAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

The AsyncTask class:

```
  private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    Url mUrl;
    public MyAsyncTask(Url url){
        this.mUrl = url;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        connect(mUrl.getUrl(),mUrl.getSourceName(),mUrl.getChoice(),mUrl.getId());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        whenToInflate[mUrl.getId()] = true;
        mProgressState += 15;
        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressState);

        if (areAllTrue(whenToInflate)) {
            inflate(1907);
            Arrays.fill(whenToInflate, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The connect method:

```
private void connect(String url, final String sourceSite, final int sourceChoice, final int i) {


    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        if (sourceChoice == 14) {
                            database.insertFixtures(response, "FOOTBALL");
                        } else if (sourceChoice == 10 || sourceChoice == 20) {
                            database.insertNews(response, sourceChoice);
                        } else {
                            if (sourceChoice == 1) response = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            database.insertNewsXML(response, sourceSite, sourceChoice);
                        }


                    } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

The VolleySingleton class:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton instance;
    private static VolleySingleton ourInstance = new VolleySingleton();
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    private VolleySingleton() {
    }

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return requestQueue;
    }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag("App");
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the class `StringRequest` and how you're managing `VolleySingleton`

Comment: Added The VolleySingleton and The StringRequest is a an object using The Android Volley Libarary(mcxiaoke.volley:library)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are updating the progress of mProgress. so thats why it is giving error. Update the progress in onProgressUpdate method AsyncTask.

Comment: Check my update, I fixed and still the UI is getting blocked, doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: ok.
But onPostExecute will only get called once after doInBackground.

Comment: Yea I know, I check if my boolean array is all true, if it is then I inflate the data as all the sites are fetched and inserted in the database

Comment: @busted13 I suspect that Hardik is right: inflating in the postExecute makes your UI available only after the execution is done.

Comment: So when/where should I inflate the data? I tried inside the doinbackground while it was inside the Connect Method and now its inside the OnPostExecute method and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange that your project used Volley inside AsyncTask, I haven't ever done such a thing before.

I suggest that you read my answers at the following questions for your reference:

[Android Volley: Static vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551668/android-volley-static-vs-object)

[POST Request Json file passing String and wait for the response Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627089/post-request-json-file-passing-string-and-wait-for-the-response-volley)

In which you will find that I use an `Interface` as the following:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(String message);

    void onResponse(Object response);
}
```

Then I pass `VolleyResponseListener` as a parameter of the method, in your case that is `connect` method.

Back to your issue, IMO, you only need to call your Volley request in your main thread (I mean `stringRequest = new StringRequest...` called directly inside `onCreate` for example)

Hope this helps!